# How to change default file system path in D8?

Tags: 8, files, path-aliases

In D8, where to change the Public File System Path to be :

sites/default/files/[nodeID]/

Do I need write a module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the public file system path globally to include a `nodeID` because there are things that can store files that do not have a `nodeID` (such as non-node entities).

Instead, you can change where files are stored per file storage field (examples: File fields and Image fields).

To do so, go to `Structure -> Content Types -> My Content Type -> Manage Fields` and then choose **Edit** for the relevant field.

Then, in **File directory**, you can use tokens to set up the path however you like.  For example:

`myfiles/[date:custom:Y]-[date:custom:m]-[date:custom:d]`

There is a link below **Help text** that you can click to see a list of available tokens.

Comment: Use [File (Field) Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) if you need extra tokens.

Comment: Is adding an author ID to the path a good practice? like `content_type/[node:author]/[date:custom:Y]-[date:custom:m]

Comment: @johnatasjmo You can configure that path however you want.  My main concern when setting the path is making sure I add any variables I will want to use as arguments (contextual filters) in Views later.